# Storing the data of website locally in the android os

Tags: android, sql-server, local, server

I have my small restaurant application. I am accessing it on the tablet (Android OS).
I just want to know that how can I store the data locally for e.g. Saving the order of a customer and when it connects to internet then data will automatically sync to the server.

One important point is that this a **WEB APLLICATION** not an android app.
Please help me with this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sqlite database can be used to store the information on the local device.